# Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (9): label

Tags: r, ggplot2, aesthetics

I get this error after I filter a simple datafarme, from 12 obs to 9, both with 2 variable...

```
tmp_Type <- c("A", "B", "C","D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L")
tmp_Sum <- c(380000.2,0,1500,4532,2,34567,29344,545,838.5,1000,0,0)
tmp_Sum <- round(tmp_Sum)

sum(tmp_Sum, na.rm=T)

tmp_Summary <- data.frame(tmp_Type, tmp_Sum) # create df

summary(tmp_Summary)

ggplot(data=tmp_Summary, aes(x=tmp_Type, y=tmp_Sum)) +
  geom_histogram (stat = "identity", aes(fill= tmp_Type)) +
  geom_text (label = (tmp_Sum), vjust=-1, hjust=0.5)

tmp_Summary <- tmp_Summary %>% filter(tmp_Sum > 0)

summary(tmp_Summary)

ggplot(data=tmp_Summary, aes(x=tmp_Type, y=tmp_Sum)) +
  geom_histogram (stat = "identity", aes(fill= tmp_Type)) +
  geom_text (label = (tmp_Sum), vjust=-1, hjust=0.5)
```

Comment: Put `label` in `aes` i.e `geom_text (aes(label = tmp_Sum), vjust=-1, hjust=0.5)`

Comment: Thanks Ronak.  That worked.  But why does the second plot call throw the error and the first Not?  Any ideas?.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the first plot worked is because you have `tmp_Sum` vector in the global environment. If you remove them after creating the dataframe the first plot would give you error as well.

```
tmp_Type <- c("A", "B", "C","D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L")
tmp_Sum <- c(380000.2,0,1500,4532,2,34567,29344,545,838.5,1000,0,0)
tmp_Sum <- round(tmp_Sum)
tmp_Summary <- data.frame(tmp_Type, tmp_Sum) 
rm(tmp_Type, tmp_Sum) #removing variables
```

Now plot.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=tmp_Summary, aes(x=tmp_Type, y=tmp_Sum)) +
  geom_histogram (stat = "identity", aes(fill= tmp_Type)) +
  geom_text (label = (tmp_Sum), vjust=-1, hjust=0.5)
```

> Error in layer(data = data, mapping = mapping, stat = stat, geom = GeomText,  :
> object 'tmp_Sum' not found

Always include `label` inside `aes`.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=tmp_Summary, aes(x=tmp_Type, y=tmp_Sum)) +
  geom_histogram (stat = "identity", aes(fill= tmp_Type)) +
  geom_text (aes(label = tmp_Sum), vjust=-1, hjust=0.5)
```

[image]